# How to fix "no such column" in sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite

everybody.
Problem with the "SELECT" request.
There is such a request:

```
    SELECT answers.idQuestion, answers.idAnswer, answervariants.points, answers.idTest FROM answervariants INNER JOIN (tests INNER JOIN answers ON tests.idTest = answers.idTest) ON answervariants.idAnswer = answers.idAnswer GROUP BY answers.idQuestion, answers.idAnswer, answervariants.points, answers.idTest HAVING answers.idTest = 21
```

```
    string query = "SELECT answers.idQuestion, answers.idAnswer, answervariants.points, answers.idTest FROM answervariants INNER JOIN (tests INNER JOIN answers ON tests.idTest = answers.idTest) ON answervariants.idAnswer = answers.idAnswer GROUP BY answers.idQuestion, answers.idAnswer, answervariants.points, answers.idTest HAVING answers.idTest = '" + idTest.ToString() + "';";
```

I expect to output 34 entries from the database, but instead get: "no such column answers.id Question". I know for sure that such a column exists. Sqlite Manager handles this query perfectly, but not Visual Studio.
What could be the problem, please help?

Comment: Is the error message an exact quote?  I ask because there is a space between *id* and *Question* in the quoted error.  That is curious since the code has no extra characters.

Comment: Please provide mode context... more of the c# code.  How are you submitting the query?  What sqlite library are you using?

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to enclose the idTest value in single quotes when defining your query in the code in Visual Studio as if you do so it will be considered as a *string* field instead of *numeric* one. Try to remove it, so that your query looks as follows:

```
string query = "SELECT answers.idQuestion, answers.idAnswer, answervariants.points, answers.idTest FROM answervariants INNER JOIN (tests INNER JOIN answers ON tests.idTest = answers.idTest) ON answervariants.idAnswer = answers.idAnswer GROUP BY answers.idQuestion, answers.idAnswer, answervariants.points, answers.idTest HAVING answers.idTest=" + idTest.ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, but unfortunately it did not work, the error remained the same:(

Comment: Please make sure that you don't have unneeded spaces after field names, i.e. answers.idTest=, not answers.idTest =

Comment: @KateOrlova  White space should not matter between operators.

Comment: @KateOrlova And in my testing, sqlite compares the integer and string values to match.  Literal values do not match, like `32 = '32'` is *false*, but no matter how I cast an integer column value and a string value on the other side, they compare to equal.   I couldn't find docs to support this, but I suppose it may assign literals on one side of a binary operator to the same type affinity as the column so that it will attempt a coercion to the same type, just as it does for storage.  Even `cast(id AS INTEGER)  =  cast('32' As TEXT)` returns *true* although docs imply that they should not.

Comment: After exploring further, casting the column by itself apparently does not "lock" the affinity of the column value, so that it will always attempt a conversion to match the other side of equals (and I assume other binary operators).  But placing the column in an expression seems to avoid an implicit coercion:  `(id + 0) = '32'` returns false when various other combinations like I had in my last comment would do some sort of conversion to make them equal.  Really all this does not actually address the PO's main question about the column name, but it was interesting exploring the suggestion.